# "Pass under an overpass" alternative

Tags: synonyms, repetition

For directions to my house, I'd like to use the phrase:

> Pass under an overpass in front of you.

However, it sounds weird with twice "*pass*", "*over*" and "*under*" etc.
Is there any better alternative or should I simply let it be?

I considered using "bridge", but there are other (car) bridges around, and this one is a (pedestrian) overpass; I do not want to confuse my visitors.

Comment: how about "go through the underpass"?

Comment: Continue beyond the pedestrian overpass until (next step in the directions)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Drew _Is there any better alternative or should I simply let it be?_

Comment: Go under the overpass, around the throughway, through the roundabout, along the crosswalk, by the highway and onto the byway, drive down the parkway and then park in the driveway.

Comment: (There are other ways you can phrase it, but there's nothing inherently wrong or weird (other than "it's in English") about what you've got.)